# Got the problem with getting ABI

Tags: blockchain, tokens

This is my code:https://gist.github.com/Puregass/f3ef64b9722c77a9290ad6369cd11172
Remix.etherium can't create ABI for my contract.How can I fix it ?

Comment: just run through `solc` with `--abi` flag

Answer (score 1):

It does, you are just getting the ABI for the wrong contract segment.

1. Choose Solidity version: 0.6.12;
2. Then compile the contract
3. Then in the dropdown here:

[image]

Choose PGS

4. Then copy the ABI below

[image]

There you go :)